# Calculate changes in columns of daily tidy data

Tags: r

Each day a company creates a value for category_1 and category_2.
A new company may enter the survey midway as company E appears on Dec 25.
Here are three days of data. So, two intervals: Dec 24-25 and Dec 25-26.

Question

For each category how many increase/decreases/no change were there over the 3 days?
For example, in cat1 A goes from a 2 to 1, B goes from a 3 to a 4, etc.

By hand I get:

cat1 - Up: 2, Down: 5, No change: 2

cat2 - Up: 6, Down: 2, No change: 1

How do I calculate the number of up/downs/no changes in an R Script?

```
library("tidyverse")

d1 <- as.Date("2022-12-24")
d2 <- as.Date("2022-12-25")
d3 <- as.Date("2022-12-26")

df <- tibble(
  company = c(LETTERS[1:4], LETTERS[1:5], LETTERS[1:5]),
  cat1 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1),
  cat2 = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 5, 9, 10, 11, 6, 5, 10, 12, 13),
  date = c(rep(d1, 4), rep(d2, 5), rep(d2, 5))
)
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using `dplyr`, assuming arranged data. Note: I changed the typo in date 3 to `d3`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(company) %>% 
  mutate(cat1_change = cat1 - lag(cat1), cat2_change = cat2 - lag(cat2)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  summarize(type = c("up", "down", "no-change"), 
            across(ends_with("change"), ~ 
              c(sum(.x > 0, na.rm=T), sum(.x < 0, na.rm=T), sum(.x == 0, na.rm=T))))
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  type      cat1_change cat2_change
  <chr>           <int>       <int>
1 up                  2           6
2 down                5           2
3 no-change           2           1
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(company = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), cat1 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 
5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1), cat2 = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 5, 9, 10, 11, 
6, 5, 10, 12, 13), date = structure(c(19350, 19350, 19350, 19350, 
19351, 19351, 19351, 19351, 19351, 19352, 19352, 19352, 19352, 
19352), class = "Date")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table` - grouped by `company`, loop over the 'cat' column, get the `diff` of adjacent elements, convert to `sign`, and rename with `factor` `labels`, `melt` to long format and reshape back to 'wide' format with `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, \(x) factor(sign(diff(x)), 
  levels = c(-1, 0, 1), labels = c("down", "no-change", "up"))),
   company, .SDcols = patterns("^cat")], id.var = "company", 
  value.name = "type"), type ~ paste0(variable, "_change"), length)
```

-output

```
        type cat1_change cat2_change
1:      down           5           2
2: no-change           2           1
3:        up           2           6
```